# Can I port my C# (SQL Server) app to a different PC?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have created a project for my college using C# and with SQL Server 2016 and SQL Server 2017 Management Studio.

It is possible that my teacher would want to test it on a different PC, so how could I run it on different PC?

The database I used was made on a local server in my laptop.

Is it possible to port it to another PC?

Sorry if port is a bad word for this but its the best thing I can come up with.

[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wec8n.png)

Comment: if your teacher wants to run your project he needs to have sql server on his PC (Laptop) . If your are worried about connection string you can set `Localhost` in your connection string and in your teacher's Pc it must has this `Server name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port is the wrong word, but I do think I understand what you want to do - "move" the application so he can run it on another endpoint.

Generally speaking:
- The other endpoint will need the same version of .Net you're dependent on
- He will need the same version of SQL Server running on his laptop

**Step 1:** Create a backup of your database

Instructions are here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/create-a-full-database-backup-sql-server

**Step 2:** Create an archive (zip/rar, whatever) of Executable

If you haven't compiled it into a standalone EXE and have library dependencies, gather them all (normally in your build directory in your project folder)

**Step 3:** Move the .bak file and archive to the other computer

**Step 4:** Restore the database

Instructions are here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/file-restores-simple-recovery-model

Notes:

- As Osman Rahimi noted in the comment, you will need to make sure your connection string in your app isn't hardcoded to your IP or machine name. It is best to use localhost or 127.0.0.1 instead.
- An alternative you might want to consider is putting the database IP into a variable you load in the .config file. That way you can concatenate it into your connection string and just instruct your teacher to make the change in the config file.

  - It could also mean you can leave the database on your workstations if it is on the same network and you have nothing blocking the required SQL Server ports between both endpoints.

The salient code/points of reference for the second point above are as follows:

```
      //import statement to reference library
      using System.Configuration;

      //reference variable in your code (for your connection-string):    
      ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SURVEYPATH_SERVER"].ToString()

      //where to add variable in config file
      <configuration>
       <appSettings>
        <add key="SQL_SERVER_IP" value="127.0.0.1" />
       </appSettings>
      </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest you can access it using IP address of your machine to browse it from different machine. make sure your firewall is open or at least the port 80 is open to be able to browse it from outside.

However if you want to **copy all code** to a different machine and run it from there you have the following options:

1) Do it manually by copying your code and do you configuration there which might take time and might even error prone especially if you miss some configuration. if you just want to copy code only and leave database in your machine, make sure your firewall is open (at least port `1433`)

2) Another way if you are familiar with containerization, you can build and share [docker's](https://www.docker.com) images and then run containers in the other machine easily.

Some articles:

[Overview of .NET and Containers](https://blog.alexellis.io/docker-dotnet-containers/)

[Introduction to SQL Server Containers](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/containers/151498/)

[Dockerizing Existing .NET MVC](https://www.ifesenko.com/blog/2017/01/18/Windows-Containers-or-Dockerize-an-existing-ASP-NET-MVC-5-application/)

3) Also you can use [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com) as a different solution to share your box and to download it there or through manual virtualization by developing your application from start (Virtualbox, VMware ..etc)

Comment: I think containers and such are a bit of overkill for a school project

Comment: @HansKesting I already mentioned all possibilities (manual, containers, vagrant or virtualization) as the question was not clear enough

Answer (score 0):

To access to database on another machine

Step 1: both machines should be  connected to  same local network

Step 2: To share database on different machine please refer the following link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-2-connecting-from-another-computer

I hope this will help you

Comment: @Hassaan Raza please try this